# In a NLP AI model, how to create a persistent context per user?

Tags: nlp, openai-api

I’m developing a new [word processor application](https://talers.io), and I’m interested in the capacities of AI and NLP to guess the end of a sentence a user is currently typing.

I would like the AI model to know about the context, i.e. the previous text that has been written (introducing characters, places, and the tone of the text).

It would work somehow like GitHub Copilot: the copilot is aware of the rest of the code, and can generate appropriate answers.

I imagine two possibilities:

1. fine-tuning a model with the other inputs of the user
2. pass a part of the current text as context to the chat API before asking to complete an unfinished sentence.

Solution **#1** is scalable (you can train your model with arbitrary amounts of text) and will produce very precise results, but there are two drawbacks:

- fine-tuning is slow (not the most annoying part),
- if there are millions of users, it means millions of different fine-tuned models. Can any NLP engine process that as of today?

Solution **#2** will work great for small texts, but it's suboptimal, as you will have to resend the context every time you start a new conversation with the AI. And the bigger the context, the worse is this solution.

How to achieve that with AI? GitHub Copilot is kind of achieving that, so I guess it's possible.

Comment: Did you make headway on this?  I'm wondering the same.